# Condition for applying become/become_user

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
- name: Create database if database does not exist
  shell: "createdb -h {{ db_host }} -O analytics {{ database }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: analytics
  when:
    database_exists.stdout != "1"
```

Currently I have a play like above but what I want is for the become/become_user attributes to also be conditional. I want it such that when ansible_env.USER = 'analytics' set become to no, and when it is not 'analytics' set it to yes. Anyone know if this is possible in ansible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use different conditions inside Jinja2 expressions (`{{ ... }}`):

```
- name: Create database if database does not exist
  shell: "createdb -h {{ db_host }} -O analytics {{ database }}"
  become: "{{ 'yes' if ansible_env.USER == 'analytics' else 'no' }}"
  become_user: analytics
  when:
    database_exists.stdout != "1"
```